# Adding datasource to XPage fails validation in complete refreshMode

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ssjs

I have a button with refreshMode set to complete. However, it doesn't seem to work when there's dataSource in place (no submission occurs)

Here's what I mean

The button:

```
<xp:button id="sendButton"
            style="float: right; margin-right:20px;"
            value="Send">

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" refreshMode="complete"
                  submit="true">

                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                print("I will never get this message printed with complete refreshMode and dataSource in place");

            }]]>
                </xp:this.action>

            </xp:eventHandler>

</xp:button>
```

And here's the dataSource:

```
<xp:dominoDocument var="requestDocument" action="openDocument"
    databaseName="${javascript: return database.getFilePath();}"
    ignoreRequestParams="true"
    documentId="${javascript:
       var conclusion = database.getDocumentByUNID(doc_source.getDocument().getParentDocumentUNID());
       var oConclusion = new OsnovaUI_document(conclusion);
       var requestDoc = oConclusion.getMainDocument(); 
       return requestDoc.getUniversalID();
       }">

</xp:dominoDocument>
```

Could somebody please tell me why this happens?

Comment: First of all, include error message with stack trace. My guess is you compute invalid UNID for documentId parameter. And your script for databseName also seems to be unnecessary, for current database just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is a failing validation formula in the classic notes form. Add a display errors ( the one with the plural) custom control to your form. It will show the error.

Comment: I've added `<xp:messages id="messages1"></xp:messages>` block but still can't see anything :(

Comment: Open the form in NotesClient and try to save with the same data and see what happens. Also try with a test form you create that you know is clean

Comment: Also, I noticed that this kind of behaviour takes place only with `xp:dominoDocument` but not with `xe:objectData`. Is it possible to get the document using the latter? I know this is a bypass solution, but just in case nothing works. Thank you

Comment: What's doc_source in your documentId logic?